# AVR32 exception: Bus Data Error

Tags: c, exception, embedded, avr32

Recently, I am facing a - to me - strange behavior in my embedded software.

**What I got:** Running a 32 bit AVR32 controller, starting the program from an external SDRAM, as the file size is too big to start it directly from the micro-controller flash. Due to the physical memory map, the memory areas are split between:

> stack (start at 0x1000, length of 0xF000) ( < 0x1000 is protected by the MPU)
>
> EBI SDRAM (start at 0xD0000000, length of 0x00400000).

---

**What happens:** Unfortunately I got an exception, which is not reproducible. Looking at my given stack trace, the following event irregular occurs:

> Name: Bus error data fetch - Event source: Data bus - Stored Return Address: First non-completed instruction

Additionally, the stack pointer has a valid value, whereas the address where the exception occurs (last entry point for fetching instructions), points into the memory nirvana (e.g. 0x496e6372, something around 0x5..., 0x6....). I guess, this has to be the "First non-completed instruction", the manual is talking about.  However, the line in my source code is always the same: accessing a member function from a data array via pointer.

```
      if(mSomeArray[i])
      {
         mSomeArray[i]->someFunction(); <-- Crash
      }
```

The thing is: adding or deleting other source code makes the event disappear and return again.

---

**What I thought about:** Something is corrupting my memory (mapping). What kinds of errors are possible for this?

- A buffer overflow?
- The SDRAM controller could be turned off, so it loses some data. That is not impossible, but rather improbably
- The stack is big enough, I already checked this with a watermark
- The Data Bus Rate and AVR clock are set correctly

---

**How to solve this:** More assert? Unfortunately I cannot debug this with AVRStudio. Anyone a hint or idea? Or am I missing something obvious?

---

### Edit:

**Mentioned approaches from users:**

- Check for addresses of function pointer and array entries
- Overwrite of stack array
- Not properly written interrupts
- Not initialized pointers
- Check for array access via `i` at crash case
- use exception handler address for illegal memory access
- use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`

---

### Late appendix to the thread: the issue was a wrong array access (wrong index was set) in an old software module, that had nothing to do with my modules. I found this by accident, it was a curiosity that it didn't appear earlier and it took me quite a while to find the line of code. I mark the only given answer as correct solution.

### Thank you all for your input.

### Take care (of your software ;))

Comment: If you call that function earlier in your code is the Bus Error triggered?

Comment: @LPs: no. It is possible, that the function can be called n times and does not crash. At any time, the exception can occur. That is why I can not reproduce it properly.

Comment: Have you got a console in your application where output data (printf)?

Comment: Yap, that is where I got my stack trace with the information I mentioned above. I got a clear stack trace with the instruction registers, but the values are out of nowhere.

Comment: You can store sensible data each time that function is called and then, after the bus error retrieve them on the console. Or, if it not block your system due to too much printf, output info each time the function is called and then look at last printed info before bus error. Very old style debug..

Comment: What is the address where the function pointer points when the bug strikes? Can you see anything strange in other members of the function pointer's struct when this happens? The line `if(mSomeArray[i])` is fishy, it suggests that you actually don't quite know where that pointer is pointing at, which in turn makes any code handling that array of pointers the most likely culprit.

Comment: C does not support exceptions, su using the tag here is questionable (the description only refers to programming languages, not hardware-exceptions). However, `AVR` is related to the smaller 8 bit MCUs. AVR32 has a completely different architecture.

Comment: @LP: I can do this type of debugging. However, I cannot see where these wrong memory values come from.

Comment: @Lundin: good point with the function pointer and the "surrounding" members. The if-statement just check for NULL pointers, as there are in a defined state and not handled with the mentioned function. How can this be tricky?

Comment: @Olaf: I agree with the c tag. The intention was to mention the language due to the buffer overflow or something like that. Thanks for changing the AVR tag.

Comment: The key point is to store input and sensible variable each time you call the problematic function. When you have those info you can start trace back to the origin of the problem.

Comment: @buffo: Sorry, my comment was about the "exeption" tag actually. I first removed that with the AVR-tag, but then re-added (and created a new avr32 tag, you could not have found that before), because it actually _is_ an exception. Actual problem is that the same word can have very different meanings.

Comment: -1 There are so many ways to corrupt memory, this question is too vague. Chances are you are overwriting an array on the stack. Or your interrupts are not written properly. Or your pointers are not initialized or... The only way to debug this is step through each line of code with a debugger, or spend days simulating the code in your head to find your bug.

Comment: assuming that the memory is not corrupted (a iffy assumption) the most likely source of the problem is not enough 'wait' states being used for the external RAM.

Comment: assuming the problem originates in the data,  what is the value of 'i' at the crash?   is the function pointer selected by 'i' pointing to the correct function address?

Comment: @MarkLakata: I agree. After other investigations I can see, that it is clearly a software bug. I think further work on this will lead to a stack corruption due to an array overflow.

Comment: @user3629249: I can see that the memory is corrupted, due to the pointer I get, pointing to a wrong address (wrong as: not a suitable area of memory). The 'i' value is a valid one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

1. Check 'i' to make sure it is within the array bounds.
2. Check the address of the function pointer that is about to be called.  It should have an address within the SDRAM.
3. See if the chip has an exception handler address it will jump to when it accesses illegal memory.  Once you are there, output some debug data
4. If your debugger allows, set a breakpoint on someFunction() when it is written.  This would catch some other function when it overwrites the function pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the further input. As further spotted: 'i' is a valid value, the function pointer address is invalid. Unfortunately I cannot use a debugger (as mentioned in the initial post). Further investigations on my exception handler could be an useful approach.